# Error en estructuras con ciclo for

Tags: c++

Estoy iniciandome en las estructuras y quise implementar el ciclo for en la creación de una. Cree un programa que registra el nombre,apellido,edad,sexo y telefono de 5 personas. Para elaborarlo utilice contadores con la funcion for, declare distintos tipos de variables. Al final de todo el programa deberia de devolver toda la informacion que se le ha ido ingresando.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//crear un programa (con estructuras) que registre la nombre,apellido,edad,sexo y telefono de 5 personas;

struct persona {

string nombre;
string apellido;
int edad;
char sexo;
int telefono;


};

int main()
{
    persona individuo[5];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
    cout<<"Ingrese el nombre de la persona "<<i+1;cout<< ": "<<endl;
    cin>>individuo[i].nombre;
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Ingrese el apellido de la persona "<<i+1;cout<< ": "<<endl;
    cin>>individuo[i].apellido;
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Ingrese la edad de la persona "<<i+1;cout<< ": "<<endl;
    cin>>individuo[i].edad;
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Ingrese el sexo de la persona "<<i+1; cout<< ": "<<endl;
    cin>>individuo[i].sexo;
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Ingrese el telefono de la persona "<<i+1; cout<< ": "<<endl;
    cin>>individuo[i].telefono;
    cout<<endl;

    }

    cout<<"Informacion registrada: "<<endl;
    for (i=1; i<6 ; i++){
        cout<<"El nombre de la persona "<<i; cout<< " es: "<<endl;
        cout<<individuo[i].nombre;
        cout<<"El apellido de la persona "<<i; cout<< " es: "<<endl;
        cout<<individuo[i].apellido;
        cout<<"La edad de la persona "<<i; cout<< " es: "<<endl;
        cout<<individuo[i].edad;
        cout<<"El sexo de la persona "<<i; cout<< " es: "<<endl;
        cout<<individuo[i].sexo;
        cout<<"El telefono de la persona "<<i; cout<< " es: "<<endl;
        cout<<individuo[i].telefono;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El programa compila y se ejecuta, el problema viene a ser que cuando termino de rellenar los datos de la primera persona, se finaliza el programa pero aparecen los espacio de las demás personas (2,3,4,5) en blanco o vacias por lo cual no entiendo.

```
Ingrese el nombre de la persona 1:
Andres

Ingrese el apellido de la persona 1:
Moreno

Ingrese la edad de la persona 1:
20

Ingrese el sexo de la persona 1:
m

Ingrese el telefono de la persona 1:
3206103053

Ingrese el nombre de la persona 2:

Ingrese el apellido de la persona 2:

Ingrese la edad de la persona 2:

Ingrese el sexo de la persona 2:

Ingrese el telefono de la persona 2:

Ingrese el nombre de la persona 3:

Ingrese el apellido de la persona 3:

Ingrese la edad de la persona 3:

Ingrese el sexo de la persona 3:

Ingrese el telefono de la persona 3:

Ingrese el nombre de la persona 4:

Ingrese el apellido de la persona 4:

Ingrese la edad de la persona 4:

Ingrese el sexo de la persona 4:

Ingrese el telefono de la persona 4:

Ingrese el nombre de la persona 5:

Ingrese el apellido de la persona 5:

Ingrese la edad de la persona 5:

Ingrese el sexo de la persona 5:

Ingrese el telefono de la persona 5:

Informacion registrada:
El nombre de la persona 1 es:
El apellido de la persona 1 es:
La edad de la persona 1 es:
1877912247El sexo de la persona 1 es:
 El telefono de la persona 1 es:
0El nombre de la persona 2 es:
El apellido de la persona 2 es:
La edad de la persona 2 es:
7085316El sexo de la persona 2 es:
╝El telefono de la persona 2 es:
1977705713El nombre de la persona 3 es:
El apellido de la persona 3 es:
La edad de la persona 3 es:
1977708437El sexo de la persona 3 es:
∟El telefono de la persona 3 es:
6422268El nombre de la persona 4 es:
El apellido de la persona 4 es:
La edad de la persona 4 es:
1977666752El sexo de la persona 4 es:
¶El telefono de la persona 4 es:
-2El nombre de la persona 5 es:

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 21.016 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu algoritmo esta bien, el problema es que al crear el arreglo `persona individuo[5];` el arreglo se crea con los indices de la siguiente forma [0, 1, 2, 3 ,4] (es decir empieza desde el 0 hasta el 4 que hacen un total de 5 elementos), y en tu bucle `for (i=1;i<6;i++){` empieza tu contador desde el 1 hasta el 5, esto genera que en tu arreglo  `persona individuo[ ];` usaras los indices 1,2,3,4,5 pero el arreglo tiene [0,1,2,3,4] entonces el indice 0 no tiene ningún dato almacenado y ademas en el ultimo recorrido del `for` cuando `i=5` asignaras una estructura a individuo[5] , pero el arreglo solo tiene desde `individuo[0]` hasta `individuo[4]`  **SOLUCION:**
te recomiendo hacer los siguientes cambios:

- El primer for para leer las personas `for (i=1;i<6;i++)` lo remplaces por `for (i=0;i<5;i++)` esto generara que al mostrar el mensaje empiece desde 0 por lo que para corregir eso el siguiente cambio es
- Cuando recibes cada uno de los datos como `cout<<"Ingrese el xxxx de la persona "<<i;cout<< ": "<<endl;` lo cambies por `cout<<"Ingrese el nombre de la persona "<<i+1;cout<< ": "<<endl;` aqui el i sera `i+1`

Comment: Te agradezco muchisimo la explicación tan detallada que me diste, ya la implemente pero me sigue dando el mismo error o un error parecido, hice algo malo?

Comment: Ya edite la publicación, por si deseas ver como quedo

Comment: En realidad el arreglo no se crea con esos índices. Lo que sucede es que, quien creó C++ decidió que los elementos tienen números enteros consecutivos como índices, comenzando con el 0 para el primer elemento.

Comment: @AndresFelipeMorenoHurtado de la misma forma tambien tienes que cambiar el segundo for que es al momento de mostrar los ya registrados cout<<"Informacion registrada: "<<endl;
    for (i=0; i<5 ; i++){ ... }

Comment: @Spider-Man Perfecto, mil gracias por todo!!